# Is the infinite tensor product of flat modules still flat?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, category-theory, tensor-products

Suppose $(M_i)_{i \in I}$ is a collection of flat $A$-modules ($A$ is a commutative ring with $1$). Is the tensor product $\bigotimes_i M_i$ still flat?

This is obviously true by induction when $I$ is a finite set, since
$$
(M_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes M_n) \otimes N \cong M_1 \otimes (M_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes M_n \otimes N).
$$
However, in the case when $I$ is an infinite set, I am not sure where to start. It seems as if there is little information online on infinite tensor products of general $A$-modules.

Comment: What definition of an infinite tensor product are you using? If $I$ has a total order on it then one reasonable defintion of an infinite tensor product is the colimit of the finite tensor products $M_{i_1} \otimes \cdots \otimes M_{i_n}$ over all $i_1 < \ldots < i_n$. This is then flat because it's a filtered colimit of flat modules. But maybe you have something else in mind?

Comment: @BrendanMurphy to define that colimit, you need specified elements in each $M_i$ (or else how do you define a homomorphism $M_{i_1}\to M_{i_1}\otimes M_{i_2}$?)

Comment: Ah you're right, I was thinking of the case of algebras (where it's just an infinite coproduct anyways). Oops

Comment: I was using the definition of an infinite tensor product via the universal property. I am following Liu's "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves," and one of the statements is "the tensor product of modules that are flat over $A$ is flat over $A$." I now think that this refers to the tensor product of two flat modules...

Comment: Is your universal property that the infinite tensor product is the universal recipient of a mulilinear map from the direct sum of the modules or from the direct product of the modules? So for example, should the countable tensor product of $k[x]$ with itself be $k[x_1, x_2,...]$ or should it contain things like $\prod_{i=1}^\infty x_i$?

Comment: I’m not sure what the convention is - the (extremely sparse) bits of information regarding infinite tensor products takes multilinear maps from the direct product, but this might be the “wrong” definition.

Comment: In that case I would expect we need some finiteness assumption on the ring, eg Noetherian (probably coherent is fine?). In a general ring (binary) tensor products and infinite direct products don't interact well